# json-server homepage is not showing

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, json-server

I created a react-app with npx create-react-app in package.json added json-server and run script.

```
"devDependencies": {
   "json-server": "0.14.2",
   "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
   "styled-components": "^2.1.1"
},

"scripts": {
    "apiserver": "json-server -p 3001 -w tools/db.json",
```

When I start the json-server with `npm run apiserver` it starts successfully. But home page does not load.

```
 \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading tools/db.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3001/posts

  Home
  http://localhost:3001

  Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
  Watching...
```

Not loading :(

[image]

Also I have json-server installed globally.
So when I start it like that:

json-server -w db.json -p 3001

It loads successfully:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create json-server.json file in root of your project, and add your custom configuration:

```
{
  ...,
  "static": "./node_modules/json-server/public"
}
```

by this solution, you call your home route from static not public directory which exists in your app.

Answer (score 3):

It is due to the `public` directory you already have in the app and workarounds are stated [here](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1100#issue-578574593)

For me, I tried passing the static URL of the public folder and it worked.

So, for you, a simple solution would be to update the `apiserver` script to the following;

`"apiserver": "json-server -p 3001 -w tools/db.json -s ./node_modules/json-server/public"`

Comment: Where is that `apiserver` script located?

Comment: It is a section in the package.json file

Answer (score -1):

in the same command line window you used to start your json-server, if you pressed s then enter it will save you a new file in the same directory as your original